# How to terminate a Razor statement in MVC4?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

So i have a line in my html like so

```
someVariable: "@(SomeClass.SomeFunction(SomeParameter))",
```

But I want to same result without the quatations so it isnt passed in as a string, when i do something like this

```
someVariable: @(SomeClass.SomeFunction(SomeParameter)),
```

it does not work, what formatting am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what does this function returns. If it is some object you could convert it to JSON using the `Json.Encode` method:

```
someVariable: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(SomeClass.SomeFunction(SomeParameter)),
```

This will ensure that the value is properly converted to a javascript object and the `Html.Raw` helper will ensure that it is left without HTML encoding it.

Comment: In this case you could simply do that: `someVariable: @SomeClass.SomeFunction(SomeParameter)`.